# PHP | Get file that is most similar to string

Tags: php, zip

Currently I have a zip folder with files in it that I do not know the filenames of. The only thing I know is that one filename is very similar to a string a have. It is literally one character off.

What I am trying to do right now is to extract only the file that is the most similar to the string I have. To extract only one file from a zip I use the following code that works:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('directory/to/zipfile') === TRUE) 
{
    $zip->extractTo('directory/where/to/extract', array('the/filename/that/is/most/similair/most/go/here'));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

I know that to check the similarity of strings I can use the following code:

```
$var_1 = 'PHP IS GREAT'; 
$var_2 = 'WITH MYSQL'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent);
```

And based on the percentage I can tell which file is most similar to the string I have. The only thing I am worried about is that ZipArchieve doesn't have a function to retrieve files from a zip without knowing the exact filename.

So I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a single file from a zip based on a string that is most similar to the filename.

Comment: The only solution that I can think on at the moment is to iterate over all the files in the zip and compare them using the `similar_text` function.

Comment: But is it even possible to retrieve a file from a zip if I don't know the full filename?

Comment: Sure, by using a loop with increasing counter you can get the names by their index (see @Mike 's answer, exactly what I meant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#105312) mentions how to list the files in a zip archive, so, all you would have to do is loop through all the file names and find the one that closest matches the string you have and then extract it.

```
$search = 'Closefilename.doc';
$za = new ZipArchive(); 

$za->open('theZip.zip'); 
$similarity = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 
    similar_text($stat['name'], $search, $sim);
    if ($sim > $similarity) {
        $similarity = $sim;
        $filename = $stat['name'];
    }
}
// Now extract $filename;
```

Comment: If I echo $filename I get all the files in the zip file.

Comment: Did you echo it inside the `for` loop or after it?

Comment: My bad. I have another variable called $filename. I changed the variable name and echo'd it outside the loop and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// Your Zip File path
$zip = zip_open( $fileName ); 

if ( is_resource( $zip ) ) {
    while( $zip_entry = zip_read( $zip ) ) {
        $zip_entry_string = zip_entry_read ( $zip_entry );
        // Compare here with similar_text 
        // If success you can write this string to file
    }
}
zip_close( $zip );
?>
```